# How to use google analytics with HTML 5 History?

Tags: html, google-analytics

I'm using HTML 5 history for my site, so, for users whose browsers support it, clicking on a link doesn't reload the whole page, but just the main area.

Google analytics doesn't track these partial page loads.  How can I get it to track it just like it does for users that don't have HTML 5 history support?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just need to register the additional pageviews by calling the `_trackPageview` function again each time your new content loads. This is called a 'Virtual Pageview' but is registered in Google Analytics in the same way as a real one. To set the path of the page you need to add an additional parameter to the function:

```
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/new/content']);
```

Comment: How would I call this each time the content loads?  Do I reload the entire script with the new URL replacing '/new/content' in what's returned via AJAX?

Comment: just call it on window.popstate like described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate - if you use history.js https://github.com/balupton/History.js/ (recommended) you put into your 'statechange' event callback. Google has implemented its own 'push' method - which calls a page at google in the background to transmit your custom data

Answer (score 6):

This is for the newest Universal Tracking Code.

So recently, I had to revisit my own answer for a new project. I noticed some issues that I should clean up.

To send a pageview programmatically, you want to send only the Path and the Query eg. for `http://example.com/path/to/resource?param=1` we will send `/path/to/resource?param=1`.

Some SPAs use HashBangs (`#!`) for their urls. So we need to send anything after the Hashbang. e.g. `http://example.com#!path/to/resource` we will send `/path/to/resource?param=1`.

The earlier version of my solution was erroneous and would fail for all urls which had a hash in the url. Also, as I was using jQuery + History.js plugin my solution was along of listening to `statechange` came from there.

Use this new code to send a pageview. It is more resilient and caters for both hashbangs and history.

```
    var loc = window.location,
        hashbang = "#!",
        bangIndex = location.href.indexOf(hashbang),
        page = bangIndex != -1 ? loc.href.substring(bangIndex).replace(hashbang, "/") : loc.pathname + loc.search;

    ga('send', 'pageview', page);
```

If you don't use Hashbangs specifically, simply change `hashbang = "#!",` to match e.g. `hashbang = "#@",`

---

The second part of this is detecting when the url changes. For this, you will need to find out from the docs of whatever library you are using.

For jQuery + History.js plugin, the code below works

```
$(window).on('statechange', function() {
    //put code here
});
```

More information can be found at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

---

```
$(window).on('statechange', function() {
    var loc = window.location,
    page = loc.hash ? loc.hash.substring(1) : loc.pathname + loc.search;
    ga('send', 'pageview', page);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ewan already stated, you should send the pageview to analytics in the window.popstate event.
So, in plain javascript, if you have called:

```
history.pushState({'statedata':''}, 'title', '/new/page/url');
```

you should simply add:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

Actually the new Universal Tracking Code automatically gets the current URL, so you don't really need to pass the extra parameter.

Comment: except when you use hashbangs.